# Creating a specific pattern using loops

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how I would make my code print the right pattern using this logic;

```
Enter len:7
Enter repeat:3
\--\--\
--\--\-
-\--\--
\--\--\
--\--\-
-\--\--
\--\--\
Bye
```

This is the code I have written;

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            if((j%repeat == 0))
                System.out.print("\\");
            else
                System.out.print("-");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("Bye");
```

However if I put in the same value for len and repeat it gives this;

```
\--\--\
\--\--\
\--\--\
\--\--\
\--\--\
\--\--\
\--\--\
Bye
```

How do I make mine work like this? I know the difference through the lines is the position is off by one position but how to implement that is my problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        if(((i+j)%repeat == 0))
            System.out.print("\\");
        else
            System.out.print("-");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("Bye");
```

i + j

Comment: This does _solve_ the problem, but it doesn't explain the reasoning behind the solution. Posts that help people solve problems in same category are more valuable. If you could add the explanation, it would greatly increase the value of this answer.